# Which white powders form acids when mixed with water?

Tags: acid-base, identification

I have a mystery acid which isn't citric, boric, or oxalic acid. When mixed with water, it smells pungent, like hydrochloric acid--though I haven't compared them side by side.

Which other white powders form a strong acid upon being combined with water? Is there any powder that decomposes into HCl when mixed with water?

(Note: the mystery acid was sold as part of a set, along with [sodium chlorite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chlorite), for generating [chlorine dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine_dioxide) for use in aquariums.)

Comment: Does it dissolve in water _completely_?

Comment: @IvanNeretin It dissolves completely except for some chalky looking impurities. (The other powder, the sodium chlorite, also leaves impurities visible in the water when dissolved.) I'll measure the solubility when I get home.

Comment: Using some of "red cabbige pH indicator" (http://www.discoveryexpresskids.com/blog/test-ph-levels-with-red-cabbage), is the solution of X in water rather acidic, or basic? In other words, "mystery acid" is based on knowing that it is an acidic material?

Comment: @Buttonwood I used full-range pH paper (not that precise), but it looks like it's pH 2 or lower. Certainly 2.5 or less. I'll have narrow-range acid pH paper next week, and that'll let me estimate whether it full disassociates. (Is that right? If not, it'll get stuck at some pH, and if so, it'll get more acidic the more I add.)

Comment: Is it sodium acetate? Because it is very soluble in water to form acetic acid. It has pungent smell and has ph of 2.4.

Comment: @NilayGhosh Thanks, that's good to know, but no vinegar smell. Plus it reacts with NaClO2 to immediately (almost violently) form ClO2, and vinegar doesn't have that effect.

Comment: @IvanNeretin What were you getting at regarding complete disolution? I found it leaves quite a bit of white "scum" floating on the top when it's dissolved. The solubility is high--at least 40g per 100g of water at around 25 deg C.

Are acids ever supplied as meta-materials with an acid gas adsorbed over another substance? I think at the very least, my mystery acid is a mix, because I think I also smell a hint of chlorine.

Comment: Is it sodium hypochlorite aka bleach (NaOCl)? It has a very pungent chlorine like smell, soluble in water to form hypochlorous acid (pH = 4.0).

Comment: @NilayGhosh I wasn't aware hypochlorite could be packaged as a solid. If so, that's probably one component of the powder, unless the powder contains/yields HCl. (Unless my nose deceives, it definitely contains chlorine. But the smell is more "aggressive" than bleach. More like HCl.) NaOCl can't be the main acid, though--if I could trust my color sense more, I would say the pH was 1.

Comment: @piojo I was thinking of some salts that hydrolyze easily.

Comment: @NilayGhosh Don't confuse people. Sodium acetate solution does not have pungent smell; more importantly, it has _alkaline_ pH rather than acidic. True, it does contain some minuscule amounts of acetic acid resulting from hydrolysis, but that doesn't make it an acid.

Comment: @IvanNeretin From a chemical engineering perspective, this powder should ideally contain (or yield) either straight HCl, or HCl and NaOCl, because either combination is used to produce chlorine dioxide when mixed with NaClO2. I'm not sure whether a salt of HCl would behave the same way. Does HCl have (solid) strong acid salts?

Comment: Did I say "salts"? I meant "chlorides" (including covalent chlorides). $\ce{PCl5}$ would behave like that, but it is most likely too aggressive to be actually used.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thanks! I have a feeling this is heading in the right direction. The material is probably moisture sensitive, due to being packaged in an extra plastic bag. It's not PCl5, since I can put it in water or drip water onto it (sorry, shouldn't even have tried that) without any apparent reaction. Next, I'll try dissolving a granule and letting it dry. If this is a hydrolyzable chloride, its size will decrease after evaporation. I can also probably tell that by seeing whether it's infinitely "soluble" in a drop of water.

Answer (score 3):

From the pH and solubility information alone, I would propose sodium bisulfate: cheap, readily available, safe in the powerfully oxidizing solution. (Possibly also potassium bisulfate.)

One way of manufacturing $\ce{HCl}$ produces sodium bisulfate as a byproduct:
$$\ce{NaCl + H2SO4 -> HCl + NaHSO4}$$ The odor of $\ce{ HCl}$ could be a minor impurity in this mystery acid. The other impurities also suggest it is not a reagent grade product.

Comment: Nice suggestion! It looks the same as the bisulfate photo on wikipedia, and based on its packaging in a plastic bag within a bottle, I suspect the mystery acid is also hygroscopic. The one wrinkle in this theory (and it's minor because I don't trust my perception) is that I thought I also smelled chlorine (like a pool smell). Still, you're likely right. I'll try to think of a way to confirm.